# Extracting a string from the start of a target string to a character

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a target string:

```
Target_string <- "aaa"
```

... and I want to return that, and all further characters up to the next "|" in a vector of strings.

For example, If I have the following vector of strings:

```
String <- c("bb|aaa_123|ccc","aaa234|bbb|NA|NA","bbb|ccc|aaab452|ddd|NA|NA")
```

My target output would be :

```
Target_output <- c("aaa_123","aaa234","aaab452")
```

I have tried gsub and str_extract, but I'm struggling with the syntax and have run out of ideas.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: `aaa[^|]*` to match 0+ times any char except a pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `lapply()` with `strsplit()` and then concatenate the results. You have to create a list to save the results of match. Also, the check of match can be done with `grepl()` inside a function defined in `lapply()`. Finally, you can collect all results with `do.call()` using `c()` function to create a vector over `L` list:

```
#Data
Target_string <- "aaa"
String <- c("bb|aaa_123|ccc","aaa234|bbb|NA|NA","bbb|ccc|aaab452|ddd|NA|NA")
#Split and check
L <- lapply(strsplit(String,split='|', fixed=TRUE),function(x) x[grepl(pattern = Target_string,x = x)])
#Bind
do.call(c,L)
```

Output:

```
[1] "aaa_123" "aaa234"  "aaab452"
```

Comment: Thanks Duck, this is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_extract` :

```
stringr::str_extract(String, paste0(Target_string, '.*?(?=\\|)'))
#[1] "aaa_123" "aaa234"  "aaab452"
```

where the pattern to extract is :

```
paste0(Target_string, '.*?(?=\\|)')
#[1] "aaa.*?(?=\\|)"
```

---

In base R you can do this as :

```
sub(paste0('.*(', Target_string, '.*?)\\|.*'), '\\1', String)
```

Here the pattern is :

```
paste0('.*(', Target_string, '.*?)\\|.*')
#[1] ".*(aaa.*?)\\|.*"
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, this is very useful. I need to spend a bit more time understanding the syntax with regular expressions!